# Aurelia - property that is 2-way bound on custom template and populates form always shows undefined in console

Tags: aurelia

I have a two way bound object in a custom element. Its two way bound to the parent.

The parent, client.ts, does a fetch for the client data based on a clientDetails  class.

The child here is the Address custom element.

When the client form is populated with a client so is the address component via the bind.

In the address.ts (child here) I have initialized the two way bind as so:

```
@bindable({ defaultBindingMode: bindingMode.twoWay }) address = new AddressDetails;
```

AddressDetails is as follows:

```
    import { Serializable } from "../../../../services/serializable/Serializable"

    import { AddressLocation } from "./addressLocation"


    export class AddressDetails implements Serializable<AddressDetails> {
        address1: string;
        address2: string;

        addressLocation: AddressLocation;

        deserialize(input) {
            //console.log("INPUT: ", input)
            this.address1 = input.address1;
            this.address2 = input.address2;

            if (input.addressLocation) {

                this.addressLocation = new AddressLocation;

                this.addressLocation.deserialize(input.addressLocation);
            }

            return this;
        }
    }
```

When a client is requested for edit it all works so if a client is populated then so is the address component.

**My problem** is that I am getting errors wherever I try and set a value thats part of the bind object. that is, If I want to set the stateShortName as per:

```
this.address.addressLocation.stateShortName = this.companyStateShortName;
```

I get the error:

```
address.ts:72 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot set property 'stateShortName' of undefined
```

As it states `this.address.addressLocation.stateShortName` is undefined.

This caused me to check if I could console.log the value of `this.address` in a "created" function as well as "bind" and "attached".

So even though I have bound this object, initialized at the start as AddressDetails it always comes up as undefined even when all the fields show values it still errors as "undefined".

Even though I have initialized this object from the start no matter where I try and access this two way bound object I cant because its "undefined"

Why cant I access it?? 
..and how do I access "this.address" or any of its members so I can, say, set one of the object's members to a value??

Below is the whole class for the "address.ts" **for context**. I get an error any time I try and access or set this.address in this class.

```
        import { HttpClient } from "aurelia-fetch-client";
        import { bindable, bindingMode, autoinject, inject, NewInstance, PLATFORM } from "aurelia-framework";
        import { Router, activationStrategy } from "aurelia-router";
        import {
            ValidationControllerFactory,
            ValidationController,
            ValidationRules
        } from "aurelia-validation";
        import { BootstrapFormRenderer } from "../../../../services/bootstrapFormRenderer/bootstrapFormRenderer";
        import { AuthService } from "../../../../services/auth/auth-service"

        import { AddressDetails } from "../address/addressDetails"
        import { AddressLocation } from "./addressLocation"

        @autoinject
        export class Address {
            @bindable({ defaultBindingMode: bindingMode.twoWay }) address = new AddressDetails;
            postcode: string;
            states = Array();
            companyStateShortName: string;

            constructor(
                private authService: AuthService) {
                this.getStateData();
            }

            created(owningView, myView) {
                console.log("CONSTRUCTOR ADDRESS: ", typeof this.address, this.address);

            }

            bind(bindingContext, overrideContext) {
                if (this.address.addressLocation.postcode === "undefined") {//we want it to match
                    setTimeout(50);//wait 50 millisecnds then recheck
                    return;
                }

                console.log("BIND ADDRESS: ", this.address);
            }


            attached() {
                console.log("ATTACHED ADDRESS: ", this.address);

            }


            // Single fetch for poplulating the states and obtaining the default state.
            getStateData() {
                const headers = this.authService.header();

                let stateDropdown = fetch("/api/selectData/GetStatesAndCompanyStateId", {
                    method: "GET",
                    headers
                })
                    .then(response => response.json())
                    .then(data => {
                        for (const key in data.stateDropDownList) {
                            this.states[key] = data.stateDropDownList[key].stateShortName;
                        }
                        console.log("ADDRESS get state data: ", this.address);
                        console.log("data: ", data)
                        this.companyStateShortName = data.companyStateShortName;
                        console.log("StateShortName: ", this.companyStateShortName)
                    })
                    .then(() => {
                        //if (typeof this.address.addressLocation != "undefined") {
                            //this.address = new AddressDetails;
                            //this.address.addressLocation = new AddressLocation;
                        //debugger;
                            console.log("this.address.addressLocation: ", typeof this.address, this.address)
                        this.address.addressLocation.stateShortName = this.companyStateShortName;
                        //}
                    });

                return stateDropdown;

            }

            // Fetch for async suburb dropdown.
            async getSuburbData(filter: string, limit: number) {
                const headers = this.authService.header();

                if (this.address) {

                }
                else {
                    console.log('undefined')
                }
                const queryStringValues = {
                    query: filter,
                    stateShortName: this.companyStateShortName
                };

                const queryString = "?" + Object.keys(queryStringValues)
                    .filter(key => typeof queryStringValues[key] !== "undefined" && queryStringValues[key] !== null)
                    .map(key => `${encodeURIComponent(key)}=${encodeURIComponent(queryStringValues[key])}`)
                    .join("&");

                console.log("queryStringValue; ", queryString)
                //console.log("initial suburb", this.address.addressLocation.suburb);

                let suburbLookup = await fetch("/api/selectData/QuerySuburbs" + queryString, {
                    method: "GET",
                    headers: headers
                })
                    .then(response => {
                        return response.json();
                    })
                    .then(addressLocation => filter.length > 0 ? addressLocation.filter(item => item.suburb.toLowerCase().indexOf(filter.toLowerCase()) > -1) : addressLocation)
                    .then(addressLocation => limit ? addressLocation.splice(0, limit) : addressLocation);  // Not really needed - its done on the server.
                //.then(suburbs => console.log("Suburbs: ", suburbs));

                //this.postCode = this.address.postcode;

                console.log("suburbLookup", suburbLookup);
                return suburbLookup
            }

            suburbSelected(item) {
                //debugger;
                //console.log("BEFORE ASSIGNMENT OF SUBURB NAME: ", item, item.postcode, this.address.addressLocation.postcode)
                if (this.address.addressLocation != null && item != null) {
                    console.log("2 changed suburb", this.address.addressLocation.suburb);
                    //this.address.addressLocation.suburb = item.name
                    var test = item.postcode;
                    //this.address.addressLocation.postcode = item.postcode;
                    //this.address.addressLocation.addressLocationId = item.addressLocationId;
                } else {
                    // this.address.addressLocation.postcode = "-";
                }
                console.log("AFTER ASSIGNMENT OF SUBURB NAME: ", item, this.address)
            }
        }





        class StateDropdownAndCompanyState {
            companyStateShortName: string;
            stateDropdownList: StateDropdown[];
        }

        class StateDropdown {
            stateId: number;
            stateShortName: string;
            stateName: string;
            stateLabel: string;
        }

        class suburbQuery {
            query: string;
            stateShortName: string;
        }
```

Comment: can you create a minimal repro?   

It is a bit hard to grasp with what you are fighting.  

just 4 files. Only the relevant parts.   
template/vm for parent component  
template/vm child element width bindable property as a class?

Comment: Thanks Alexander.. not sure how to do that so might take a little time but will have a go.  I think this might be as a result of the fetch on the parent but again not sure.

Comment: Irrelevant to a solution. I am just here to point out `setTimeout(50);//wait 50 millisecnds then recheck` would not do what you want in JavaScript ...

Comment: Am I on the right track thinking its to do with the parent fetch promise not completing before I try and access that object variable?

Comment: Note that the class members you are declaring are mostly `undefined`. In AddressDetails, you do not create a new AddressLocation object - you only do that during deserialization which you do not call in this example.